# Problem to render a component dynamically with React Router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm working on a personal website and I have a problem rendering a component dynamically using React Router. To me, everything seems correct but for some reason, it's not working.

I tried to follow the documentation and watched a couple of tutorials but I have been stuck for a long time so I feel like I need help on this one.

In this component, I want to render the 'Articles' component dynamically using the id

```
class JobCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],   
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          data: result        
        })
      );
  }


  render() {

     const { match } = this.props;
      const { data, value } = this.state;

      return (
        <>
             <div>
                {results.map((job, id) => (
                  <div key={id}>
                    <div key={job._id} className="blog-card">
                      <div className="meta">
                        <div className="photo">
                          <img src={job.img} alt="logo" />
                        </div>    
                      </div>
                      <div className="description">
                        <h5>{job.position_name}</h5>
                        <p className="read-more">
                          <p>{job.location}</p>
                          <p>
                            <span className="learn-pow">
                              {" "}
                              <Link
                                to={{
                                  pathname: `${match.url}/${job._id}`,
                                  state: job
                                }}
                              >
                                {job.workplace_name}
                              </Link>{" "}
                             Enter Location
                            </span>
                          </p>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            }

            <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Articles} />
        </>
      );

  }
}

export default JobCard;
```

And here is the component that i want to render:

```
import React from 'react';

const Articles = ({ location }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{location.state.name}</h1>
    <h2>{location.state.email}</h2>
    <h2>{location.state.place}</h2>
  </div>
)

export default Articles;
```

When I click on the Card the URL is right so I get the id but I don't have access to the Article component. I tried to console log but nothing appears.

Comment: Why do you have this route somewhere in the middle of your component? `<Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Articles} />`?

Comment: It's the component that i want to render, shouldn't it be there ?

Comment: Try to put all routes at one place maybe app.js

Comment: Also share the error logs

Comment: I don't get any error, that is the problem haha

Comment: In `JobComponent`, where is `results` (as in, `results.map`) defined?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Articles} />
```

try doing this

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={Articles} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i already tried but i got the same issue.
The id is in the url but the component is not rendering

Comment: Inside `JobCard`, what is the result of `match`?

Comment: ```{path: "/job", url: "/job", isExact: true, params: {…}}
isExact: true
params: {}
path: "/job"
url: "/job"
```
Here is my log for match

Comment: You may need to try updating your code first. You're accessing `results.map` inside the render method, instead of calling `.map` on `this.state.data`.

Comment: ```{this.state.data.map((job, id) => 
```

You mean like this ?
I got the same result unfortunately, my JobCard component render perfectly but when i click to get the article it's not working.

What's make me really confused is that on the url i got the id of the card 

```http://localhost:3000/job/5ccc770c6ac54350001f0954
```

Comment: have you tried doing a console.log inside of the Articles component to see if the route component is being called at all?

Comment: Yes i did, the Articles component is not being called since nothing appear on the console.log